# How to configure Spring Batch RetryPolicy in workflow.xml file?

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on introducing a customize retry policy in my Spring Batch job. Following is my sample step define in the workflow. But i am not getting where to define/configure the "retry-policy"?

Please help.

```
<job id="job1" job-repository="jobRepository">       
      <step id="step1">        
         <tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager"  >
             <b:bean parent="tasklet1" scope="step">
                    <b:property name="scriptFile" value="script"/>                    
             </b:bean>
            </tasklet>
            <next on="COMPLETED" to="step2"/>
            <next on="FAILED" to="error"/>
        </step>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on official site on how to configure Spring Batch RetryPolicy for chunks.

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
             commit-interval="2" retry-limit="3">
         <retryable-exception-classes>
            <include class="org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException"/>
         </retryable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

step1 is configured with a limit for the number of times an individual item can be retried, and a list of exceptions that are 'retryable'.

you can take a look for more details on how retry works [Retry.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#retry)

Here is another example [spring-batch-retrytemplate-example](https://github.com/lhinze/spring-batch-retrytemplate-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml)

Comment: Thanks Feres. But I am looking to define customize retry policy in the step configuration I shared. Please see.

Comment: you may specify your own RetryPolicy and plug it into the chunk.
<batch:tasklet>
  <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="20" retry-policy="myRetryPolicy"/>
</batch:tasklet>

Comment: The link to the example is dead 2019-06-21